# Video Concatnation using javacv

Tags: android, ffmpeg, javacv

I have integrated this Javacv for concatenating 2 videos this code works find when i was using 2 videos recorded from rear camera,but when i record 1 video with front cameara and another with rear camera then another half video is rotated upside down
Is there any specific settings while recording from front camera,

I have used this library from github
https://github.com/sourab-sharma/TouchToRecord

Here is the recording file 
[Video Recording](https://github.com/sourab-sharma/TouchToRecord/blob/master/JavaCvVideoRecorder/src/com/javacv/recorder/FFmpegRecorderActivity.java)

Please give me some solution on this

Thanks